# How to "save as" everything on a remote server directly?

Tags: chrome, web-browser, firefox, web

I am using browsers like **firefox** and **chrome**.

Many times I need to use **"save as"** a webpage rather than only **bookmark** it.

What "save as" does is saving a html page and a folder with a lot of other stuff in it  on a **local drive**.

This way it is okay for me to view everything when I don't gain access to the Internet.

What can I do to directly **"save as"** everything on a **remote server**  ?

I am asking for a software that can download a page directly onto my own server, not on my local folders. "Save as " can only download a page on local folder.

Comment: Does this have to work with the browser’s "Save as" dialog? Or are you fine with a stand-alone tool for this? With a browser add-on that uses a different button? With a web application which you can install on your server?

Comment: Nothing needs to be installed on my server. It would be best that "add-on" or extension can be working together with my browser's "Save as"  function.

Comment: @SleepingOnaGiant'sShoulder Without any server component, that will hardly work. As it is your own server: would it be OK to install e.g. some web app there – which e.g. stores the page you tell it to in its own database, and offers a web frontend to browse stored pages? If so, I might have a candidate for you.

Comment: to  Izzy: Yes, my own shared server. I think it might be okay for me to install something on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because most servers won't share everything they have (e.g., my website won't give you its password file), and many don't even provide a way to list everything they'll share. The closest you can get in general is to use a [web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) that tries to find everything on a website by following links. Try, for example, `wget` with the `--mirror` option.

Answer (score 0):

At one time I was using [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to locally mirror remote sites.

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.

It worked well at the time and the local copies still function, but I haven't used it for some time now as I no longer have a need for it.